How to calculate maximal distance error given a 3D covariance matrix of object's position error?
Given the 3x3 position error covariance matrix, I need to calculate the maximal offset of the position with 95% confidence level
I've read this paper, it solves the problem, but only for 2x2 covariance matrix case.
Very appreciate any help

Please show your efforts. What problems do you encounter when extending the result of the paper?
